# How to pass parameters to RedCloth (Textile processor) from Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, textile, redcloth

The [RedCloth FAQ](http://redcloth.org/faq) describes using the `fold_lines` option to disable hard breaks. What's the easiest way to pass `fold_lines` to RedCloth when it's called as part of Jekyll's build process?

(am I just missing something in the [Jekyll configuration guide](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `_config.yml` file, you can use :

```
redcloth:
  hard_breaks: false
```

From Jekyll `converters:textile.rb`

```
# List of attributes defined on RedCloth
# (from https://github.com/jgarber/redcloth/blob/master/lib/redcloth/textile_doc.rb)
attrs = ['filter_classes', 'filter_html', 'filter_ids', 'filter_styles',
            'hard_breaks', 'lite_mode', 'no_span_caps', 'sanitize_html']
```